# HEX as input type in HTML without color?

Tags: html, forms, input, hex

I am trying to have an input field that takes hexadecimal numbers/symbols as input. However, apparently **HTML5** doesn't support hexadecimal numbers as a type for input(except for the color input type)

Is there a way I can implement hexadecimal numbers as input and still be able to live-check if the input that the user is inputting is a valid hexadecimal number? (I really want to have the browser notify the user if their input is invalid *BEFORE* they submit the form)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression: `0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+`, and check on keypress or when user clicks off input box

```
console.log(/0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+/.test('hexCode'));
```